# difficult understanding Margin property

Tags: c#

Margin property described by MSDN, quote:

> The Margin property describes the distance between an element and its child *(why not parent?)* or peers.

But how to decide if the margin describes the distance between an element  and  its child(parent) or peers? here are two examples: 
first one:

```
<GroupBox Header="Experience" Height="200"  Name="yearsExperience"  Width="200">
    <StackPanel   Margin="0,0,0,0" >
       <RadioButton Content="Up to 1 year" Height="16" Name="novice" Width="120" Margin="0, 10, 0, 0" />
        <RadioButton Content="1 to 4 years" Height="16" Name="intermediate" Width="120" Margin="0, 20, 0, 0" />
         <RadioButton Content="5 to 9 years" Height="16" Name="experienced" Width="120" Margin="0, 20, 0, 0" />
         <RadioButton Content="10 or more" Height="16" Name="accomplished" Width="120" Margin="0, 20, 0, 0" />
       </StackPanel>
</GroupBox>
```

second one:

```
<GroupBox Header="Experience" Height="200"  Name="yearsExperience"  Width="200">
    <Grid  Margin="0,0,0,0" >
       <RadioButton Content="Up to 1 year" Height="16" Name="novice" Width="120" Margin="0, 10, 0, 0" />
        <RadioButton Content="1 to 4 years" Height="16" Name="intermediate" Width="120" Margin="0, 20, 0, 0" />
         <RadioButton Content="5 to 9 years" Height="16" Name="experienced" Width="120" Margin="0, 20, 0, 0" />
         <RadioButton Content="10 or more" Height="16" Name="accomplished" Width="120" Margin="0, 20, 0, 0" />
       </Grid>
</GroupBox>
```

Apparently in the first example, the margin describes the distance between peers (RadioButtons), while in the second example ,the margin describles the distance between RadioButtons and Grid (parent) top, and RadioButtons shall overlap each other. That's really tricky, so what's  really going on?

Answer (score 0):

You can think of margin as a set distance between the object you're applying it to and anything else around that object, regardless of if it's a parent or peer.

I don't know what the "technical" definition is, but that's how it always works.

Padding on the other hand is the distance between the border of  object and anything contained within  object.

Answer (score 0):

StackPanel and Grid components have different types of inserting children. At both examples margins works same where the locations changes according to the layouts. At StackPanel each children is added after the last children in the layout related to the StackPanel properties such left to right, bottom to top and so on. At Grid the positions of children must be given by the coder, if not each children is added at the anchor of the layouf, as default top-left corner, so that they overlap each other if any position is assigned.